# Recover cleared file content

Tags: linux, windows, storage, ntfs, data-recovery

I was working on a report using [typora](https://www.typora.io/) markdown editor, which is a beta version now.

After finishing the report and saving it, I have opened it to review and correct typos. While I was editing, the program hangs and I killed its process.

when I tried to open the file again, I've found it a clean file. So is there any way to recover the last saved content of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open preference panel, under “Editor” section, click the “Recover Unsaved Drafts” button to find some writing drafts auto saved by Typora.

Source -> http://support.typora.io/Version-Control/